# Cannot access member of an object via pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

This problem seems like a trivial one but I am unable to get my head around it.

I am trying to add a node by passing in a root element to a function `insert`. The function first checks if the current root is empty, if it is, it simply creates a new node and set it as a root. My first attempt was something like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node(int x) {
            data = x;
        }
};

void insert(Node *node, int x) {
    cout << &node << "\n";
    if(node == NULL) {
        node = new Node(x);
    }
}



int main () {
    Node *aNode;
    aNode = NULL;
    insert(aNode, 8);
    cout << aNode << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This of course didn't work since I was passing pointers by value which was causing `aNode` to be still `NULL` and with some googling I came to know I need to pass pointers by reference, my second attempt was something like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node(int x) {
            data = x;
        }
};

void insert(Node **node, int x) {
    if(*node == NULL) {
        *node = new Node(x);
        cout << *node->data << "\n"; //gives error but program runs fine without it
    }
}



int main () {
    Node *aNode;
    aNode = NULL;
    insert(&aNode, 8);
    cout << aNode->data << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Now that worked without the `cout` in insert function since the `cout` in `main` printed `8` which is what I wanted but compiler gave error `request for member 'data' in '* node', which is of pointer type 'Node*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)` while at `cout` of insert. I changed the insert as follows to run some tests and results were confusing

```
void insert(Node **node, int x) {
    if(*node == NULL) {
        Node *bNode = new Node(x);
        cout << bNode << "\n"; // prints address of bNode
        cout << *node << "\n"; // prints NULL which is correct
        *node = bNode;
        cout << *node << "\n"; // prints the same address as of bNode
        cout << bNode->data << "\n"; // prints 8
        cout << *node->data << "\n"; // gives error WTF!!!
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: The `->` operator has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `*` operator, so `*node->data` is the same as `*(node->data)` and as such is trying to dereference `data`, which is not a pointer. You need to use `(*node)->data` instead.

Comment: Hey thank @RemyLebeau that worked, I knew it was a stupid mistake, can you give me some resource which can explain this dereferencing thing in depth?

Comment: in c++ use references rather than `Node**` as arguments, your intent is much clearer and you wont get these errors

Comment: "*in c++ use references*" - in other words, use `Node* &node` instead of `Node **node`, then you can use `node` as-is instead of using `*node`

Comment: @RemyLebeau tx for the clarifying comment. Umair the reason its clearer is because Node** could also mean 'here is a 2d array of Nodes'

Comment: Now that you know the issue, can you pare this down dramatically to make it a useful explanation/answer for others?

Comment: @DavisHerring done :)

Answer (score 0):

@RemyLebeau comment was spot on and pointed out the exact problem. So here is the solution.

**Problem Background**

So I had a pointer to an object of type Node `aNode` and had a function `insert(Node *node, int x)`. I wanted the function insert to check if given pointer to node doesn't point to anything then create a new node and set the reference in provided node. The expectation was that after setting the reference `aNode` will point to the newly created node as well. However it was a false expectation because I was passing the pointer by value instead of reference which meant `node` in the function `insert` was a different one than `aNode`

**Buggy Solution**

So the solution was to pass reference of `aNode` to function `insert`. So I changed my function call to `insert`, to this

```
insert(&aNode, 8);
```

And change the function definition of `insert` to this

```
void insert(Node **node, int x)
```

That fixed the problem, since `**node` was now dereferened to the address of `aNode` and I was able to get its value by simply dereferencing `node` by `*node`. The problem occured when I tried to access members of `Node` by `*node->data`. The reason was that `*` and `->` are actually operators and `->` has higher precedence than `*`. So while evaluating `*node->data` it was actually executing in this way `*(node->data)` which means compiler was actually trying to dereference `node->data` instead of `node`. The quick solution was just to access data like this (*node)->data.

**Right Solution**

Although through parenthesis I was able to achieve the desired behavior but the syntax was ugly. The right solution as @pm100 pointed to use reference in function definition instead of dereferencing it twice which means declare function like this

```
void insert(Node *&node, int x)
```

instead of like this

```
void insert(Node **node, int x)
```

That enabled to access node members simply like `node->data` instead of `(*node)->data`

If you are new to pointers like me do watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxvv9krECNw